# Powertrain vs Drivetrain vs Driveline

Tags: drivetrain

I did a bit of research and I'm really confused.

Need a clear distinction between all three.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Powertrain** - From the engine, through the transmission, down the drive shaft and out to the wheels. All parts which make the car go down the road.

**Drivetrain** - Basically the same as the powertrain, sans the engine. You're talking about everything which makes the car go, except the engine.

**Driveline** — This is the drivetrain minus the transmission, meaning it includes only the driveline components

Comment: Thanks but isnt there a difference between the drivetrain and the driveline?

Comment: @DarkNRhalKarl - Nope. You may be thinking of a *drive shaft*, which is different. It's the part which runs between the transmission and the differential on rear wheel drive vehicles.

Comment: Also is the suspension part of the powertrain?

Comment: @DarkNRhalKarl - IMO, no. Others may think differently. The suspension supports the vehicle, allows easy transition over uneven road surfaces, and helps provide traction. You could take the suspension away and the vehicle would still go down the road ... it'd be a crappy ride, but it would still go. If you take any of the other parts away I've mentioned, you cannot say the same.

Comment: Final clarification. What group does a tire rod fall under?

Comment: @DarkNRahlKarl - Neither. It's a steering component. It neither transmits drive energy (ie: drivetrain), nor does it suspend the vehicle (ie: suspension).